# Comparing the Kazhdan-Lusztig and Steinberg pre-orders

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, schubert-cells, canonical-bases, open-problems

Both Kazhdan-Lusztig and Steinberg have defined pairs of preorders on $S_n$.  Kazhdan and Lusztig's preorders come from their basis:

> We write $x\leq_L y$ if any left ideal spanned by K-L basis vectors which contains $C_y$ also contains $C_x$.  Similarly for $x\leq_R y$ and right ideals.

Note that $x\leq_L y$ if and only if $x^{-1}\leq_R y^{-1}$, so all the information is in one of these preorders.

Now, we can define a geometric preorder satisfying similar properties, following Steinberg.  Let $\mathfrak{n}$ be the usual strictly upper-triangular matrices in $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ and let $\mathfrak{n}\cap\mathfrak{n}^w$ be its intersection with itself conjugated by $w$.   We let $x\leq_l y$ if $B\cdot (\mathfrak{n}\cap\mathfrak{n}^y)\subset B\cdot (\mathfrak{n}\cap\mathfrak{n}^x)$, and $x\leq_r y$ if $x^{-1}\leq_ly^{-1}$.

> Do the preorders $\leq_L$ and $\leq_l$ coincide?

It's a theorem (look, for example in Appendix B of Borho and Brylinski, Differential... III) that the equivalence relations induced by them (the left cells) do; they're both distinguished by their $Q$-symbol under Robinson-Schensted.

> Do these preorders have a nice description in terms of Robinson-Schensted?

**EDIT:** After speaking with various people, I believe this is an open question, and quite an interesting one in my opinion.

Comment: Note that your link leads to the Steinberg paper, while your slightly earlier post links to the BB paper.   Anyway, Appendix B of the latter refers to the never-published 1977 Warwick preprint by Spaltenstein (then Lusztig's student) titled *Remarques sur certaines relations d'equivalence dans les groupes de Weyl*.  In type A, where all nilpotent orbits are special, it seems plausible that the pre-orders and not just the equivalence relations should coincide.  An interesting question apparently not addressed in Spaltenstein's later Springer LN volume.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I fixed that (had both of them open in long DigiSchrift links, and copied the wrong one).

I saw the Spaltenstein reference, but have found no evidence that preprint ever saw the light of day.  It's not on MathSciNet, nor does Googling the title turn up more than a couple other papers which cited it.

Comment: Spaltenstein's preprint of course preceded the KL work, but their treatment in type A probably isn't so closely linked to Hecke algebra formalism.    Still, it's hard to put the pieces together.